# SKAction followPath + rotation

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I am trying to use SKAction rotation on repeatForever + followPath around a circle, but the rotation doesn't work. So is it possible to combine rotation + followPath ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and your code is at...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do mean follow path and rotation? Do you mean you want it to follow the path and always rotate so that it points in the direction it is going?

If so there is an action...

```
[SKAction followPath:path asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];
```

Pass in the circle path that you want the node to follow and set `orientToPath` to YES and this will rotate the node so that it points the direction it is currently going around the path.

i.e. the opposite of this. Passing NO would mean the sprite always faces North (for instance) while following the path.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your path action called `path` and your rotation action called `rotation`, before you call your repeatActionForever method you create an action group:

```
SKAction* rotateAndMove = [SKAction group:@[path, rotation]];
```

Repeat the above action forever for simultaneous movement and rotation.